# How to update the TextView in the activity by clicking a button in ListView?

Tags: java, android

Here i have a ListView of my products. I want to update the totalBill TextView, which is in the activity but not in the ListView, whenever user clicks on the add button in the ListView. My problem is, the CustomAdapter doesn't allow to update the TextView, which is in the activity class, on button click. How to achieve this?

```
        tvId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemId);
        tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        tvPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
        tvQty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        plusButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        minusButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
    }
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int qty = Integer.parseInt(tvQty.getText().toString());
            double itemPrice=Double.parseDouble(tvPrice.getText().toString());
            tvQty.setText(String.valueOf(++qty));
            ShoppingCart2 cart=new ShoppingCart2();
            cart.addQuantity(qty, itemPrice);
        }
    });
```

The above code is in the CustomAdapter and the below is in the activity class.

```
    public void addQuantity(int quantity, Double itemPrice) {
    try {
        Double totalPrice = quantity * itemPrice;
        totalBill = totalBill.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(totalPrice));
        totalBill = totalBill.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        tvTotalBill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalBill);
        tvTotalBill.setText(totalBill.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting a NullPointer Exception in the addQuantity function. Is there any other way to get this done.

Comment: Post the code you have

Comment: I have added the code. Please check it

Comment: What is `cart`? If that is a reference to your `Activity` then it theoretically should work.

Comment: cart is an instance of the activity in which I call the method addQuantity. But the textview tvTotalBill is showing null value

Comment: And what is `totalBill`? I don't see that instantiated anywhere. Have you set a breakpoint to check that `totalBill` has a value? Also see if `quantity` and `itemPrice` have a value when you enter that function so you know where it goes wrong. Are you getting an exception when you run this code?

Comment: Ya. It's showing NullPointer Exception in the line
        tvTotalBill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalBill);

Comment: Post the logcat in your question using the edit button and show where/how you are instantiating the `TextView`

Comment: I passed the tvTotalBill textview to the CustomAdapter's constructor and set the values inside the Adapter and it's working. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working :) You can post as an answer and accept it so it may help others